# Need to trigger javascript modal on homepage only once

Tags: magento2, javascript, home-page, modal-popup

We want to have the registration popup come up on (only) our homepage whenever a customer has not visited before. I think I can chase down the information on setting a cookie for the one-time behavior, but I'm trying to figure out how to inject the javascript necessary to call the existing cleversoft social-login modal.

The current modal is triggered by clicking a 'Create Account' link on the header bar which appears to call the following function:

```
        $('.registerpopup').on('click',function(event){
            qsModal_l.modal('closeModal');
            qsModal_r.modal('openModal');
        });
```

Presumably the first line just makes sure it isn't already open and since I want to do this on page load if the cookie is not already set, the modal would not be open so I'm assuming I only need to call the second line:

```
            qsModal_r.modal('openModal');
```

So basically I want to make sure that the cleversoft javascript is loaded into the page then call this function on only the homepage, but I'm not sure to go about it.

I see discussions about adding a javascript source to the  portion of cms_index_index.xml and/or the design portion of the content->page if I put the code in a .js file, but I'm not sure how to reference such a js file if I added it to the theme's web/js directory.

I also see comments about loading such a file with require.js but I'm not sure if calling a single function requires that much coding. (keeping in mind I also need to do the cookie check though, maybe it is?)

So what is the 'best practices' way of doing this sort of thing from the home page?

EDIT:
It appears the modal vars are local scope, but they can be accessed via the container. So I have a javascript file similar to this for just testing the ability to open the modal as app/design/frontend/Cleversoft/custom/web/js/regpopup.js:

```
require(["jquery"],function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('div#zoo-register-form').modal('openModal');
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Now I need to know how to add a reference to load that to the  of the layout.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to add `JS` is with **requirejs**.

To add your js via `Requirejs` in **homepage**, then you run your script just **ONCE** :

Your js file is: `regpopup.js`

**app/design/frontend/Cleversoft/custom/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            myscript: 'js/regpopup'
        }
    }
};
```

**app/design/frontend/Cleversoft/custom/web/js/regpopup.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict";
       return function myscript()
       {
           alert('hello Modal');
           $(document).ready(function() {
               setTimeout(function() {
                   $('div#zoo-register-form').modal('openModal');
               }, 1000);
           });
       }
});
```

**app/design/frontend/Cleversoft/custom/Magento_Cms/templates/{yourfile}.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'mage/cookies', 'myscript'], function($, myscript) {
        if (! $.cookie('cookiemodal')) { //check if cookiemodal doesn't exist
            $.cookie('cookiemodal', 'ok'); //we set a cookie name="cookiemodal" value="ok"
            myscript();
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Info:** don't forget to :

- clean the cache
- clean `var/view_preprocessed` content
- clean `pub/static` content
- deploy the static content = `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

### Update:

To execute the js part just if customer is logged in: in `{yourfile}.phtml`

```
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); ?>
<?php $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session'); ?>
<?php if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) : ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(['jquery', 'mage/cookies', 'myscript'], function($, myscript) {
            if (! $.cookie('cookiemodal')) { //check if cookiemodal doesn't exist
                $.cookie('cookiemodal', 'ok'); //we set a cookie name="cookiemodal" value="ok"
            myscript();
            }
        });
    </script>   
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that last part with how to include it in the template was the piece that was missing in all of the dozens of examples I found. It didn't do me a hell of a lot of good to get the syntax right for the requirejs or config files if I couldn't actually call a function in the right place ;)

Comment: woops, spoke to soon. Using example as shown I get: "Uncaught TypeError: myscript is not a function" in the phtml where myscript(); is called.

Comment: I think I got this part working, but now I'm trying to add a check to see if the customer is logged in and can't find a single working example that I can figure out  how to piece into this.

Comment: Please, Look my update

Comment: The method examples I saw that included references directly to the objectManager inevitably attracted multiple comments warning "don't directly access the objectManager"

Answer (score 0):

You can add your script to the `<head></head>` block in your theme under `Magento_Cms/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml`. Then just make sure your script is checking for the cookie value you have set. If you haven't figured the cookie part out I can update this answer to include that part.

`app/design/YourTheme/ThemePackage/Magento_Cms/cms_index_index.xml`
OR
`vendor/yourtheme/layout/Magento_Cms/cms_index_index.xml`

Add

```
<head>
    <script src="Vendor_Modulename::js/your-js.js"/>
</head>
```

The script will be loaded when the homepage set in the CMS is loaded and your script will run. Modify your script to return a function to make sure it runs.

```
define(
    'jquery'
, function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //Check for cookie first!
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('div#zoo-register-form').modal('openModal');
            }, 1000);
        });
    };
}
```